# Permission denied on Drupal.org

Tags: drupal, contacts, cvs

When I'm logged in to Drupal.org, I noticed a couple of links that are linked to my profile but when I click on these links, it says "You are not authorized to access this page":

These are the two links I'm trying to access:
"CVS edit link for bocalig" (http://drupal.org/node/872054)
"your personal contact form" (Your Dashboard > Profile > Edit > Contact Settings)

Does anybody know why I wouldn't have permission to access these particular pages?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are a Drupal.org CVS administrator, you cannot use the edit CVS link for user pages.

And you cannot contact yourself. This is [a bug in Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/345541) so just ignore it.